# How to fix The POM for XXX:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins

We tried to build our project(Spring Boot 2.0.3 with Maven 3.3.9 dependency management)Jenkins Tool(Linux environment).Its saying build failure showing the following message in console "The POM for org.actus:ACTUS-Core-1.0:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available".ACTUS is our custom java library developed by us and its in the local repository also.

This is the first time we started using Jenkins Tool. There are some other modules which depends on this same ACTUS jar.Those are also failing.I have searched for solution on internet.Some people said,make changes to settings.xml file.But in our development machine ,we cant find any such type of settings.xml file(in .m2)

remaining  all dependencies are normal spring boot dependencies only.This is the only one external or custom jar.Using mvn install, we kept in maven local repo.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.actus</groupId>
    <artifactId>ACTUS-Core-1.0</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: As described in the Maven documentation (https://maven.apache.org/settings.html):
There are two locations where a settings.xml file may live:
The Maven install: ${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml and a user’s install: ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml.
If the file itself is missing, you can add it yourself, manually - Maven will start using it

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain as much I can to solve your problem. I hope you are looking for settings.xml to update your maven Nexus repository. If you don't know about nexus repository, it's kind of public repo where you will get all open source dependency.

1. In your case, from your organization, you should have a private nexus repository and upload ACTUS-Core jar to there.
2. Then update your settings.xml file to use your company nexus repository. (Please check comments, it will be available in M2_HOME location)
3. So while you execute *mvn install* automatically it will upload in your private repository.
4. Now, in your pom.xml mention the same nexus repository. (It's optional)
5. Then, in your Jenkins script, you have updated this nexus repo.

So, the key point is you should have your own repo to upload ACTUS-Core jar and need to access the same while you building in Jenkin tool.

**OR ELSE**

If you find all the above activities in pain / not possible then I can suggest a short cut solution.

1. Create a *lib* folder under your project name ( same hierarchy as *src*) then add your ACTUS-Core.jar and commit that file along with your source code.
2. Then, update your pom file like below. It will work.

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>test</artifactId>
            <version>11.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/fileName.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank You Mr.Satz. It worked. I have chosen the 2nd option.